# What sound formats can the .NET library handle?

Tags: .net, audio, media-player

I'm thinking of writing my own media player, just something basic to suit my own needs. I'm just wondering what formats the .NET libs can handle? All I can find in the libraries is WAV support, which is no surprise. Are there any other libraries that abstract other formats or what? Or can I do it better in another language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**

.NET Framework handles wav files only, so you should use other decoders for various formats

For example for MP3 files you can use LAME

[.NET Lame MP3](http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/38-windows/2033-net-mp3.html)

For other formats you can use FFDSHOW

[FFDSHOWAPI](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/wiki/devel%3acontrolling?s%5b%5d=ffdshowapi)

**Solution 2**

If you can do, you can develop your application with C++ so you won't need any wrappers

**Solution 3**

That's not the answer of your question but if you don't want to start from scratch. You can use

[Windows Media Player COM Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4)

or

[VLC COM Object](http://wiki.videolan.org/C_Sharp)

and embed Windows Media Player or VLC Player into your .NET application in a much more simpler way, so you don't have to deal with decoders or file formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF, then the `MediaElement` can be used to play pretty much anything that Windows can play.

Windows comes with various APIs for decoding and encoding audio, and to use them with .NET you'll need interop wrappers. I've written about how you can make use of the interop wrappers that come with NAudio to convert between any format that Windows supports [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET).